# Is it possible to lose files simply from moving them folder to folder?

Tags: files, filesystem, directory, shared-folders

I recently moved a file from one folder to another, and in the process, lost the files. All I did was drag the files from one folder to another, yet it somehow got lost on the way. I have tried every searching function I could - find command, locate command, kfind, etc. The files seem to be gone, and I have no idea why. Can someone please help me?

To be more specific, here is what I tried:

1. "Search your computer" app on the sidebar. This yielded nothing, and as a note for anyone with a similar issue in future, this couldn't even find specific files that aren't lost.
2. locate -i "filename*" in the terminal. This yielded no results, or any response form the system at all (I was expecting it to tell me something to the effect that nothing was found, but it would just give me a fresh shell prompt). I also tried the exact file name, but with similar results.
3. I then tried the find command- find / -type f -name "filename*", and got a lot of search results that were stymied by being denied permission. I then added a sudo in front of the identical command, and it was able to search more directories, but funny enough, it still was denied permission to a certain directory, though one I'm confident wouldn't hold the files in question.
4. I installed kfind, and it yielded nothing.
5. I used the magnifying glass in the home directory, and it didn't find the files either.

Re: the [other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872780/searching-using-ubuntus-terminal), I decided that the question asked there put too much of an emphasis on the search function, which doesn't seem to be the problem, so I created this question that put more of an emphasis on the filesystem and the crazy fact that all I did was attempt to drag the folder containing my files, so that I could at least ascertain if such an issue is possible.

Re: the [destination folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872786/is-it-possible-to-lose-files-simply-from-moving-them-folder-to-folder#comment1354181_872786), it was indeed a shared folder, though I hate to admit that in retrospect I'm not sure if it had been mounted when I attempted to move the files to it. In that case, however, wouldn't it just act like a normal folder, i.e. it wouldn't simply lose files?

Comment: Possible to loose them if you didn't specify `mv` command properly

Comment: @Serg While that's possible, judging from the description, "All I did was drag the files from one folder to the other," that doesn't seem like the most likely explanation. Hopefully the author of this question will provide a much more detailed explanation soon, since no real advice can be given until then. pmse234: I don't know when you'll get a chance to [edit], but if we do end up closing this as *unclear*, then when you [edit] it to give the necessary details, it'll be automatically considered for reopening. Even if both your questions about this do get closed, please still pick just *one*.

Comment: You say "Re: the destination folder, it was indeed a shared folder, though I hate to admit that in retrospect I'm not sure if it had been mounted when I attempted to move the files". If you mounted the filesystem afterwards, your files are hidden by the mount, they are in your local filesystem. Unmount the shared folder and look there again. No search, just go inside the mount point and look.

Comment: It's possible if the folder was not mounted at the time you copied and is mounted now.  Provide the contents of your `fstab` and specify *exactly* the full path where you moved from and where you moved to.  [Edit] your question to provide that info and then drop me a note @fabby

Comment: Both user596137 and @Fabby got it- I had to unmount the folder, which strangely did not appear in the gui for my home directory afterwards, but I was able to salvage my files in it from the shell. Thank you all- I'd like to mark one of these replies as the answer, but I don't seem to see a green check mark like I think I'm supposed to.

Comment: @user596137: Missed your comment.  As you were the first one to have thought of this, would you care to post an answer???

Answer (score 4):

You say:

> Re: the destination folder, it was indeed a shared folder, though I
>   hate to admit that in retrospect I'm not sure if it had been mounted
>   when I attempted to move the files

If you mounted the filesystem afterwards, your files are hidden by the mount, they are in your local filesystem. Unmount the shared folder and look there again. No search, just go inside the mount point and look.